# Javascript generated calendar showing different in mozilla firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I make custom calendar in javascript.

In firefox (1st image) calendar is properly generated, but in chrome (2nd image) is "upside-down".

[image: In Firefox]

[image: In Google Chrome]

There is [`JSFiddle example`](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhrvsob/)

Can anyone tell me why this happening?

In fiddle example I put button, and calendar is genereting, in some div, but in my webapp, instead in div (`document.getElementById('cntcal').appendChild(tbl);`), calendar is generated in form (`document.form[0].appendChild(tbl);`).

p.s. sorry for weak English, I hope you people will understand problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested now in Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 and It is working great. What version of chrome you used for testing ?

Comment: Is it possible because my Version is 32.0.1700.102 m ?! I'll update now and try again.

Comment: Yes browsers are updated and new elements are added bugs are fixed. I looked into your code and could not find reason of such error.

Comment: well, that is insane... firefox create update almost twice at one month... :-D ... thx again.